# IHealthCheck to add multiple checks instead of one

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, health-check

In my application I need to dynamically add health checks based on registered dependencies in `IServiceCollection` aka services.

My plan is to iterate through services and add all necessary health checks dynamically. The issue here is, it would work only if my library that adds health checks is a very last call in the chain of `services.Add` so that all the dependencies are registered at that point.

Ideally I'd want to be able to add multiple results using IHealthCheck. Any ideas how I could make it all work?

Comment: Would it be possible to register a list of IHealthCheck instead? As far as I know, IServiceCollection is not really intended dynamic registrations.

Comment: @JonasH it is possible overall but not possible in my case because I develop a library, not an aspnet core app. So I don't know what exactly will be registered.

Comment: Could you explain how the registered dependencies relate to your health checks? I.e. are there certain types you register based on configuration, or based on what types are found in different assembly files? Would the health check use the registered types? I ran into a problem that might be similar. Some more context might help me to answer this.

Comment: @DavidWalschots We have multiple downstream services that are registered as clients in services, it would be cool to find them all automatically and add a healthcheck per each of them. I'd iterate similar to this `services.Where(s => [check if service descriptor's underlying type is of a certain base type]).ToList().ForEach(s => [add healthcheck])`. Something similar to this.